# Dependent dropdown menu in different collection

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, dropdown

I'm new in Meteor. I'm trying to make dropdown menu dependent in other dropdown. The first one for client name in Customers collection & the second for the client address in Addresses collection. I've 2 collections Customers & Addresses. This is my code but don't know what to do next.

EDIT: i put both templates in another template called new order

HTML:

```
<template name="selectClient">
  Client Name :
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled>Choose client name</option>
  {{#each custom}}
  <option>{{clientName}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
</template>
<template name="selectAddress">
  Address:
<select class="select" name="Choose the address">
  <option selected disabled>Choose the address</option>
  {{#each address}}
  <option>{{addressName}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
</template>
```

main.js

```
Template.selectClient.helpers({
    'custom': function(){
        return Customers.find();
    }
  });
  Template.selectAddress.helpers({
    'address': function(){
        return Addresses.find();
    }
});


var clientName= $('[name="newName"]').val();
    var mobNumber = $('[name="newMob"]').val();
    var age = $('[name="age"]').val();
    var radioValue= $('[name="gender"]').val();
    Customers.insert({
    clientName: clientName,
    age: age,
    radioValue:gender,
    createdAt: new Date()
    });

var addressName = $('[name="addressName"]').val();
    var detail = $('[name= details]').val();
    Addresses.insert({
      addressName: addressName,
      detail: detail,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });

Customers = new Mongo.Collection('customers');
Addresses = new Mongo.Collection('addresses');
Mobile = new Mongo.Collection('mobile');
```

Comment: Are you using Meteor with Blaze, Angular or React?

Comment: no, I didn't use any library

Comment: Did you read any of these tutorials? https://www.meteor.com/tutorials

Comment: the indermediate one

Comment: <template name="selectAddress">
  Address:
<select class="select" name="Choose the address">
  <option selected disabled>Choose the address</option>
  {{#each address}}
  <option>{{addressName}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
</template>

Comment: <template name="selectClient">
  Client Name :
<select class="select">
  <option selected disabled>Choose client name</option>
  {{#each custom}}
  <option>{{clientName}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
</template>

Comment: Template.selectClient.helpers({
    'custom': function(){
        return Customers.find();
    }
  });
  Template.selectAddress.helpers({
    'address': function(){
        return Addresses.find();
    }
});

Comment: this is my codes but I don't know what should i do next

Comment: If I can suggest you something at this point: you should not put the code in comments like that. You may want to add it to your question, so it's easier for people to help you out. Just my suggestion.

Comment: okay thanks for your suggestion..I already wrote my code

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two templates in parallel (and not in a parent-child relation) you may use a `ReactiveVar` to cache the current selected client name:

```js
const selectedCustomer = new ReactiveVar()
```

Note, that it needs to be accessible for both templates. Either you declare it with both templates in one file or your use `import` / `export` to provide access over many files.

Now your customers `select` needs to have a `value` assigned  to each `option`, so we can cache it on selection change:

```html
<template name="selectClient">
    Client Name :
    <select class="select-customer">
        <option selected disabled>Choose client name</option>
        {{#each custom}}
            <option value="clientName" selected="{{#if selectedClient clientName}}selected{{/if}}">{{clientName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
</template>
```

I renamed it's class, to prevent confusion in naming, to `select-customter`. Noticed the `{{#if selectedClient}}...` code? We will use a helper to restore the last selected state on the dropdown. Otherwise your dropdown selection will reset on the next rendering cycle:

```js
Template.selectClient.helpers({
  'custom': function(){
    return Customers.find();
  },
  selectedClient(name) {
    const selected = selectedCustomer.get()
    return selected && selected.clientName === name
  }
});
```

We get the selected customer from the cache and check if the current option's value is the same. If true we can flag the option as `selected`.

Now you still need an event that covers the selected client:

```
Template.selectClient.events({
  'change .select'(event, templateInstance) {
    // get the value using jQuery
    const value = templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget).val()
    // update the ReactiveVar
    selectedCustomer.set({ clientName: value })
  }
})
```

It saves the selected value (currently the `clientName`) in a query-able format. Now in your adresses you just need to query all `Adresses` documents using the cached selected client:

```
Template.selectAddress.helpers({
  'address': function(){
    const query = selectedCustomer.get() || {}
    return Addresses.find(query);
  }
});
```

If a client is selected it will server as the query, otherwise all adresses will be returned.

The good thing is, that this `ReactiveVar` already provides you the capability to trigger a new rendering cycle if it updates, since your helpers' code relies on it and Blaze automatically resolves this for you.

#### Modificatopns

This code assumes, that `Adresses` have a relation to `Customers` by a field named `clientName`. If you have stored the relation by using other fields, such as `_id` - `clientId` you need to modify your code accordingly.

You could also hide the second dropdown and only display it, if there is a value in `selectedCustomer`.

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort,but how can i make a relatin between Customers & Addresses by a field named clientName.

Comment: I got this erorr..'“Reactive HTML attributes must either have a constant name or consist of
a single {{helper}} providing a dictionary of names and values. A
template tag of type BLOCKOPEN is not allowed here.”.. Soryy, but as i said I'm new in Meteor & this is my first project.

Comment: oh I missed some code, I updated the html template. Regarding the relation - Please post the schema of Customers and Adresses so it is easier to explain.

Comment: Okay Thanks alot, It works with me..I edited my Question & wrote how the value should show in my atabase but i didn't use simpleschema but if it necessary, could you help my in it..Thanks in advance